# Can I bind windows http.sys to another port than 80

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp

We are using the http port 80 to run a SAP Portal response to an URL.
We made a restart to the server and the Operating System uses now port 80:

```
C:\Users>netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0.0.0:80

TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4

TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1540

UDP    0.0.0.0:8082           *:*                                    1540
```

The process PID 4 is the operating system and using the ProcessExplorer application it figures out that is the Http.sys that is running now on port 80.

It was stopped and deactivated the http.sys but this has dependencies, and one is the World Wide Web Publishing Services (IIS) that we need.

Can I bind the http.sys port to be another port so that the dependencies that are related with this service could run without problems?

Thanks
Sílvia

Answer (score 2):

Http.sys does not open ports on its own. It does on at the request of an application. Http.sys can be accessed by any application.

Reconfigure the application. There is no way to configure Http.sys.

Answer (score 0):

Generally requests leaving are bound to a random port whereas the services the server you make requests to are bound to a specific port

Answer (score 0):

Give your OS a second IP and [bind http.sys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307219(v=vs.85).aspx) to one IP and SAP Web Application Server to another.

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::1
```